# Swiper works on local but not when deployed

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, swiper.js

I'm using react, styled components, and swiper to create an image slider. It works fine on local but seems to break when deployed (AWS Amplify).

The dev tools reveal the `.swiper-pagination` and `.swiper-slide`s outside the `.swiper-wrapper` for the deployed version.

```
export default function DraggableImageSlider({
  imageList,
  description,
}: Props) {
  return (
    <StyledDraggableImageSlider
      modules={[Pagination]}
      pagination={{ type: "fraction" }}>
      {imageList.map(({ id, imageUrl }) => (
        <StyledSwiperSlide key={id}>
          <SlideImage src={imageUrl} alt={description} />
        </StyledSwiperSlide>
      ))}
    </StyledDraggableImageSlider>
  );
}

const StyledDraggableImageSlider = styled(Swiper)`
  width: 100%;
  cursor: grab;

  > .swiper-pagination-fraction {
    width: 59px;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 16px;
    left: 318px;
    font: ${({ theme: { font } }) => font.displayDefault12};
    color: ${({ theme: { color } }) => color.neutral.textWeak};
    border-radius: 16px;
    background: ${({ theme: { color } }) => color.neutral.backgroundBlur};
    backdrop-filter: ${({ theme: { backdropFilter } }) => backdropFilter.blur};
  }
`;

const StyledSwiperSlide = styled(SwiperSlide)`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  &::before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(
      180deg,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.138832) 9.16%,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 26.27%
    );
  }
`;

const SlideImage = styled.img`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
`;
```

**Solved**

```
export default function DraggableImageSlider({
  imageList,
  description,
}: Props) {
  return (
    <StyledDraggableImageSlider>
      <Swiper modules={[Pagination]} pagination={{ type: "fraction" }}>
        {imageList.map(({ id, imageUrl }) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={id}>
            <SlideImage src={imageUrl} alt={description} />
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </StyledDraggableImageSlider>
  );
}

const StyledDraggableImageSlider = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  cursor: grab;

  .swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    > .swiper-pagination-fraction {
      width: 59px;
      height: 32px;
      padding: 8px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 16px;
      left: 318px;
      font: ${({ theme: { font } }) => font.displayDefault12};
      color: ${({ theme: { color } }) => color.neutral.textWeak};
      border-radius: 16px;
      background: ${({ theme: { color } }) => color.neutral.backgroundBlur};
      backdrop-filter: ${({ theme: { backdropFilter } }) =>
        backdropFilter.blur};
    }
  }

  .swiper-slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    &::before {
      content: "";
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: linear-gradient(
        180deg,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.138832) 9.16%,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 26.27%
      );
    }
  }
`;

const SlideImage = styled.img`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
`;
```

Comment: It seems styled-component and Swiper are conflicting in some way. I moved away from `styled(Swiper)` to using classNames assigned by Swiper.